# How do I insert into a pre-existing rows from another table for a whole column Oracle SQL?

Tags: oracle, sql-update

I am trying to insert postal codes from one table(insert into pre-existing rows) to another table of addresses that have null postal codes. The address_id in postalcodes corresponds to the address_id in address table.


The postal codes table has the address_id and postalcode.
Here is the postal codes table:

[image: postalcodes schema]
[image: postalcodes table]

Here is the address table:

[image: Address schema]

[image: Address table]

This is what I have tried.

```
INSERT INTO address ( postal_code )
    SELECT
        postalcodes.postalcode
    FROM
        postalcodes
    WHERE
        address.address_id = postalcodes.address_id;
```

But it gives me an error:

```
Error starting at line : 26 in command -
INSERT INTO address ( postal_code )
    SELECT
        postalcodes.postalcode
    FROM
        postalcodes
    WHERE
        address.address_id = postalcodes.address_id
Error at Command Line : 32 Column : 9
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "ADDRESS"."ADDRESS_ID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: The error says there isn't an `ADDRESS_ID` field on the `ADDRESS` table, and the image you included of the data seems to confirm this. ??? Also, please don't post images of code or data - it makes it sufficiently difficult to reproduce your problem that most people won't take the time to type your code in. Instead, post code and data as text in a code block so that people can simply copy it and use it when needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You want an `update`, not an `insert`:

```
UPDATE address
    SET postal_code = (SELECT p.postal_code
                       FROM postalcodes p
                       WHERE a.address_id = p.address_id
                      )
    WHERE postal_code IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert the rest of the values for address. You can't insert postal codes by themselves. Or are you trying to update the values of zipcodes for existing addresses?. Creating zip codes into address will give you NULL, NULL, NULL, ZIP_CODE, NULL, ECT. IF it doesnt give you an error based on some primary key constrain

Maybe trying selecting

```
  FROM
        postalcodes, Address
```

SQL hAs no ida what address is unless you select from it.